# I have only 9.54 GB root , I don't have space anymore. So I freed 15 GB disk in order to extend my root partition with it. But now unable to extend

Tags: gparted, resize

[image: Partition layout]

I want to allocate 15 gb free space to /dev/sda6. Can it be done without moving or any damage to system/data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible if you use a live USB/CD system.

**Step by step guide**:

1. Find an USB drive with ~1.5 GiB of free space

   - *I highly recommend that you back up any important data from that USB drive before continuing*
2. Download any recent Ubuntu image from the [Download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (if you don't have one lying around already).
3. Launch the *Startup Disk Creator* application

   1. Add the downloaded Ubuntu image using the *Other…* button of the first section
   2. Select your USB drive from the second list
   3. Start installation by clicking on *Make Startup Disk*

Now reboot and boot from the USB-Stick. Once you see the desktop on the USB system:

1. Connect to the Internet as usual
2. Launch the *Ubuntu Software Center*
3. Install *GParted* as usual
4. Launch *GParted*

Now start with the first NTFS partition (`/dev/sda3`):

1. Right-click on it's entry in GParted's partition list
2. Select *Resize/Move* from the menu
3. In the dialog: *Drag* the partition from the right all the way to the left: [image: Sample screenshot]
4. Confirm with the *Resize/Move* button in the bottom right

Next you have to make the extended partition (`/dev/sda4`) larger:

1. Again, right-click on it's entry and select *Resize/Move* from the menu
2. This time, in the dialog: *Increase* the size of the partition by dragging it's left handle all the way to the left: [image: Sample screenshot]

Now **repeat** everything you have done with the first NTFS partition (`/dev/sda3`) with the second NTFS partition (`/dev/sda5`).

Finally repeat what you have done for the extended partition (`/dev/sda4`) for your root partition (`/dev/sda6`).

The final list of pending operation should look similar to this:
[image: Sample screenshot]

Once you're confident that you have done everything correctly, click on the *Apply* button, confirm the warning, and get a coffee. It'll take a while for the all operations to complete…

Answer (score 0):

You could use parted or gparted to do this from a live CD since the partitions must not be in use while this is done for extending this should be done before resizing the filesystem, when shrinking a partition you should first resize the filesystem then the physical partition.

Resizing the filesystem is done by resize2fs command if it is an ext[2-4] filesystem.

Usually this is safe but there is always the risk that you could lose your data if external events cause the process to be interrupted such as a power failure so always back up critical data first.

Comment: He can't resize it because the free space isn't next to it, so parted/resize2fs are out.

Comment: You can also move the existing partion, check out the other answer which gives more details on that.

Comment: That was kind of my point: you have to move it, and that requires gparted, rather than parted/resize2fs, as you point to.

Comment: gparted is just a graphical front end to parted so yes you can move partitions with parted the command is "move [partnum] [start] [end]" https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/move.html

Comment: The move command was removed 5 years ago with version 3.0, along with the filesystem format and resize support.